# Why does Swamp Thing refer to himself as Swamp Thing?

Tags: dc, swamp-thing-the-series

At the end of the intro credits of the *Swamp Thing* live-action TV show, he says

> I was once a man. I know the evil that men do. Do not bring your evil here. I warn you. Beware the wrath of...**Swamp Thing**!

While his adversaries like Dr. Arcane call him nasty things all the time, his friends refer to him by his name, Alec.

**So why does he refer to himself as *Swamp Thing*?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming his reasoning in the show is the same as in the source comics, it's because he no longer sees himself as a human, but some kind of disgusting ***Swamp Thing***.

[image]

Comment: Indeed, in at least some of the comics, Swamp Thing is a distinct entity from Holland with Holland's memories. If my memory serves, Swamp Thing and Holland have existed at the same place and time.